# SensorTag 2 accelerometer range issue

Tags: android, sensors, iot

I am using Sensortag 2 for accelerometer with android and below is the code am using to enable the 3 axis of the accelerometer as well as the Wake-On-Motion. [CC2650 SensorTag User's Guide](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2650_SensorTag_User's_Guide) here says that the 8-9 bits are used for the acceleration range 0=2G,1=4G,2=8G,3=16G. The weird thing is that 8G is always on besides that am writing 00 (on 8-9 bits) I never get 2G.

```
characteristic=gatt.getService(MOVE_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(MOVE_CONFIG_CHAR);

characteristic.setValue(0b0000000010111000,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16,0);

gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

Can anyone help me please?? it really gets annoying.

Comment: Are you using any javascript on this? Or the javascript TAG was added by mistake?

Comment: am sorry that was a mistake